# How to set scrollbar to web browser control when document.body size increases?

Tags: windows, winforms

I am working on C# win from.I am created one user control which is holding the HTML type of information and displaying it in web browser control(web browser control placed in user control)all user control filled with information and display to the users as per requested(by date &  time).
but i fixed the size(Height & width)  of web browser. when information is larger then web browser it should show the scroll bar so user can scroll it.
this all user control i filed with information and placed in table panel.then table panel object reference is given to other table object (which is in another C# project). and then this table panel is added with panel control and display it.

Problem is that when size of user control's web browser control changed(I checked sized in Document Completed event and set the  web browser.Scroll Bars Enabled = true;) the information which is holding by web browser will not displaying.

Following is my code

```
private void wbContainer_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        if ((this.wbContainer.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Size.Height > this.wbContainer.Size.Height))
        {
            this.wbContainer.ScrollBarsEnabled = true;
            this.wbContainer.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

User control is added in table panel

```
public TableLayoutPanel createInfoSection(string arg_startDateTime, string arg_endDateTime)
    {


        Control objControl = null;
        int Rows = 3;
        objTablePageNotes = new TableLayoutPanel();

        // Initialized tableLayoutPanel property

        objTablePageNotes = setTablePanelProperties(objTablePageNotes);


        //returning the collection of html information
        InformationCollection objInformationCollection = new  InformationCollectionManager().GetInformationCollectionData(arg_startDateTime, arg_endDateTime);


        if (objInformationCollection != null)
        {
            if (objInformationCollection.Count > 0)
            {

                foreach (InformationList objList in objInformationCollection)
                {
                  //this will return control with filling the html information
                    objControl =ControlFactory.getControl("InfoTemplate",objList.HtmlInformation);

                    objControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

                    objTablePageNotes.SetColumnSpan(objControl, 1);
                    objTablePageNotes.Controls.Add(objControl, 1, Rows);
                    objTablePageNotes.ResumeLayout(true);
                    objTablePageNotes.RowStyles.Clear();
                    objTablePageNotes.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
                    objTablePageNotes.RowCount = Rows;
                    Rows++;
                }
            }
        }
        return objTablePageNotes;
    }
```

then this table panel object ref is assigned to

```
 tbPanelNoteSection = new CanvasDesignHandler().createInfoSection(_STARTDATE, _ENDDATE);
```

finally it added to panel control

```
 this.pnlPage.Controls.Add(tbPanelNoteSection);
```

Comment: private void wbNoteContainer_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            if ((this.wbNoteContainer.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Size.Height < this.wbNoteContainer.Size.Height))
            {
                this.wbNoteContainer.Document.Body.Style = "overflow:hidden";
            }
            
        }

Answer (score 0):

I add in DocumentCompleted event :

```
 if ((this.wbNoteContainer.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Size.Height < this.wbNoteContainer.Size.Height))
        {
            this.wbNoteContainer.Document.Body.Style = "overflow:hidden";
        }
```

Problem get solved..!